# Constructing a simple join

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to do a simple join with the following tables, but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

Table 1:

```
grad_code  award_level  total
1.1010     2            10
1.1010     3            4
3.0104     2            33
```

Table 2:

```
grad_code  occ_code openings
1.1010     22-1193  91
1.1010     55-2112  2
2.0011     22-1193  53
3.0104     99-4909  919
```

Desired result:

```
grad_code  award_level  occ_code  total  openings
1.1010     2            22-1193   10     91
1.1010     2            55-2112   10     2
1.1010     3            22-1193   4      91
1.1010     3            55-2112   4      2
3.0104     2            99-4909   33     919
```

So in the first table, the pairing of grad_code and award_level comprise a unique key, and the same for grad_code and occ_code in Table 2. Also note that any grad_code in Table 2 that does not exist in Table 1 is ignored.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do an INNER join on grad_code.

```
SELECT t1.grad_code, t1.award_level, t2.occ_code, t1.total, t2.openings
FROM Table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON (t1.grad_code = t2.grad_code)
```

Comment: Wow. I knew I wasn't crazy. I had tried this, and thought I was missing values. But it turns out I just can't read. Thank you for your help!